# Can I publish games with adult content to Android Market?

Tags: android, content-rating

I have a very old adult (e.g. boobs and stuff) arcade game (think Delphi 7/DirectX 8 age), that currently is backported to Droid. Can the game be published to Android Market? Are there any age restrictions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android Market has a very restrictive adult category. So you probably can't. But, you can publish your application on alternative markets that allow adult content.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously you can't. You'll have to host it on your own.

See developer [content-policy](http://www.android.com/us/developer-content-policy.html).

Comment: As much as they claim that content policy, there are items of several of those categories in the Market anyway. For one, spyware/malware is apparently rampant and there have been a lot of articles in the press about this. Point is, you might be able to publish such content anyway, but SyaZ has already pointed out the risk involved.